# nested ressources, still requires unnested base ressource in rails3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

I seem to require in Rails 3.1 for a nested resources both, instead of having photo just nested:

```
resources :photos
resources :gallery do
  resources :photos
end
```

Otherwise my form_for will not work for photos to submit or galleries to view:

```
<%= form_for ([@gallery, @photo],:html => {:multipart => true}) do|f| %>
```

Complaining on show of gallery:

```
No route matches {:id=>#<Photo id: 23 ...
```

Is that normal behavior, I always want my users to only be able to create photos in the context of a gallery, but now they can also access photos/new while I would only let them access gallery/:id/photos/new

Answer (score 0):

Routes can be tricky. Sometimes using the plural instead of the singular form causes an error, especially for path helpers. The plural of "Gallery" is "Galleries"

```
>> "Gallery".pluralize
=> "Galleries"
```

Check your routes with `rake routes`, I think for your purpose you should use the plural form

```
resources :galleries do 
  resources :photos
end
```